# After you took/after you take?

Tags: verbs

Let's say you are giving instruction to a person who is trying to locate his friend's house. And you say:

> Go down this xxx street, then turn left onto the third street, and its just sits around the second or third house after you **took** the left turn

Or

> Go down this xxx street, then turn left onto the third street, and its just sits around the second or third house after you **take** the left turn

Which is correct? **Took or take**

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if "xxx" is a placeholder for a street name, you should know that you should not use "this" in front of a named street.  It's just, "Go down Main Street...." If you want to emphasize that Main Street is the same street that you're standing on right now, you either use a hand gesture, or you say something like, "Go down Main Street right here...."

Comment: Oh I see, thx, very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Take** would be correct.

*took* is the past tense of *take*. In the example you gave in your question, you're speaking in the future tense - "You *will* do this, after you *do* that,", not "You *did* this after you *did* that."

"took" would be appropriate if you were explaining what you did in the past - "After I *went* down Main Street, I *took* a left onto Snake Oil Avenue." Since that happened in the past, you use past tense.
But when you're giving directions for someone to do *in the future*, you use future tense. "After you *go* down Main Street, you *will take* a left onto Snake Oil Avenue."

"took" is for when it happened in the past, "take" is for when it will happen in the future.