# Why is "bought" used instead of "buy" when the main clause has "will"?

Tags: tense, verbs, conditional-constructions

I just met a sentence, that is

> If someone **bought** it already, then that item **will** not show up.

It obviously refers to future, but why is *bought* used instead of *buy*?

I consider this same as AFTER, and [After you took/after you take?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163354/after-you-took-after-you-take) says  "You will do this, *after* you do that,".

I am so confused about this two. Both refer to the future, why is one in the past and the other is in the present?

Comment: If someone bought it (in the past), then it will not show up (in the future). Not sure where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is looking from the perspective of the point in the future when the item shows up or doesn't. From that point, the buying is in the past (I would say *has bought* rather than *bought*, but the choice of present perfect vs past is usually stylistic).

You can tell that it is from that perspective because of the adverb *already*, which is usually relative to now, or to the temporal focus, rather than to some arbitrary time - in this case, it signals that the temporal focus is after the buying.

You could say *If somebody buys it previously*, with the same meaning; but to my ear *If somebody buys it already* does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing, agreed. The sentence is referring to a metaphorical man and making reference to cause-and-effect of the recent past, then the present. If I bought the apple seller's only apple yesterday, then you wouldn't be able to buy that apple today, because I already have it. It sounds almost like a word problem for the meaning of zero.